Stochastic and deterministic trends in "Forecasting: Principles and Practice"
Section 9.4 of Forecasting: Principles and Practice (2nd edition) discusses stochastic and deterministic trends in dynamic regression models (regression with ARIMA errors). The authors write:

There are two different ways of modelling a linear trend. A deterministic trend is obtained using the regression model
$$y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \eta_t, \tag{1}$$
where $\eta_t$ is an ARMA process. A stochastic trend is obtained using the model
$$y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \eta_t, \tag{2}$$
where  $\eta_t$ is an ARIMA process with $d=1$. In the latter case, we can difference both sides so that
$$\Delta y_t = \beta_1 + \Delta\eta_t, \tag{3}$$
where $\Delta\eta_t$ is an ARMA process. In other words,
$$y_t = y_{t−1} + \beta_1 + \Delta\eta_t. \tag{4}$$

In my understanding, both cases include a deterministic linear trend. The second case also includes a stochastic trend. So the first case is just the deterministic trend and the second case is deterministic + stochastic trends. (And the deterministic linear trend will dominate the stochastic trend asymptotically, so the level of the time series will behave mostly like the deterministic trend over the long run.) Yet Forecasting: Principles and Practice do not mention the deterministic trend in the second case. Am I missing anything?

I got a response from Rob J. Hyndman. According to him, this is a matter of terminology; some references use the terms in the way of Forecasting: Principles and Practice. (So my conclusion is that I am not missing anything.)
